# Canvas to support a scrollable stock graph

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, scroll

I would like to draw a graph of a stock on a canvas.
The canvas has an initil size lets say 300 (height) x 1000 (Width).

The stock has been trading for more days that can fit into the visual part of the Canvas
I would like to drag (scroll) the visual part of the canvas around and see the non visual parts that are hidden "behind". i.e see trading days that are not initially displyed.

Would appreciate any ideas or pointers to get me on the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two canvases - a canvas inside a canvas.  The outer canvas would be fixed in size (1000 x 300), but the inner canvas would be as large as you want it to be.  Set the `ClipToBounds` property of the outer canvas to `True`.

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Stock
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ListBox.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Chart : Window
    {
        private Point _capturePoint;
        private double _captureLeft;
        private double _captureTop;

        public Chart()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);

            _capturePoint = e.GetPosition(chart);
            _captureLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(chart);
            _captureTop = Canvas.GetTop(chart);

            if (_capturePoint.X > 0 && _capturePoint.X < chart.RenderSize.Width &&
                _capturePoint.Y > 0 && _capturePoint.Y < chart.RenderSize.Height) 
            {
                CaptureMouse();
            }

        }

        protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
            ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseMove(e);

            if (Mouse.Captured == this)
            {
                var currentPoint = e.GetPosition(chart);
                var diff = Point.Subtract(currentPoint, _capturePoint);

                Canvas.SetTop(chart, _captureTop + diff.Y);
                Canvas.SetLeft(chart, _captureLeft + diff.X);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Stock.Chart"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ListBox" Height="300" Width="300">
        <Canvas Height="300" Width="1000" x:Name="viewport" ClipToBounds="True">
            <Canvas x:Name="chart" Background="Green" Width="2000" Height="1000" Canvas.Top="20" Canvas.Left="10" >

            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks alot, This is what I was looking for,It looks as I might run into a performance issue when scrolling. If I do that will be a separate issue.